# Is there a simple way to compute a "smooth" function with the following characteristics in C/C++?

Tags: c++, function, math, graph, interpolation

In order to specify some things first: The user should be able to create a graph by specifying 3 to 5 points on a 2D field. 
The first and the last points are always at the bounds of that field (their position may only be changed in y direction - not x). The derivation of the graph at these positions should be 0.
The position of the 3rd and following points may be specified freely. 
A graph should be interpolated, which goes through all the points. However, this graph should be as smooth and flat as possible. (please apologize for not being mathematically correct)

The important thing: I need to sample values of that graph afterwards and apply them to a discrete signal. Second thing: Within the range of the x-Axis the values of the function should not exceed the boundaries on the y-Axis.. In my pics that would be 0 and 1 on the y-Axis.
I created some pics to illustrate what I am talking about using 3 points.

Some thoughts I had:

1. Use (cubic?) splines: their characteristics could be applied to form such curves without too many problems. However, as far as I know, they don't relate to a global x-Axis. They are specified in relation to the next point, through a parameter usually called (s). Therefore it will be difficult to sample the values of the graph related to the x-Axis. Please correct me when I am wrong.
2. create a matrix, which contains the points and the derivations at those points and solve that matrix using LU decomposition or something equivalent.

So far, I don't have in depth understanding of these techniques, so I might miss some great technique or algorithm I haven't known about yet.

There is one more thing, that would be great to be able to do: Being able to adjust the steepness of the curve via the change of one or a few parameters. I illustrated this by using a red and a black graph in some of my pictures.
Any ideas or hints how to solve that efficiently?

[image]
[image]
[image][image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you understand how splines are arrived at?

### Summary of doing splines

You break the range into pieces based on the control points (splitting at the control points or putting the breaks between them), and plop some parameterized function into each sub-range, then constrain the functions by the control points, artificially introduced end-point constraints, and inter-segment constrains.

If you've counted your degrees of freedom and constraints right, you get a solvable system of equations which tells you the right parameters in terms of the control points and away you go.

The result is a set of parameters for a piecewise function. Generally a piecewise continuous and differentiable function, because what would be the point otherwise.

### How you can use that in this case

So consider making each interior point the center of a segment which will be occupied by a peak-like function (Gaussian on a linear background, maybe) and use the end points as constraints.

For `n` total points you'd have `D*(n-2)` parameters if each segment has `D` parameters. You have four end-point constraints `f(start)=y_0`, `f(end)=y_n`, `f'(start) = f'(end) = 0)`, and some set of match constraints between the segments:

```
f_n(between n and n+1) = f_n+1(between n and n+1)
f'_n(between n and n+1) = f'_n+1(between n and n+1)
...
```

plus each segment is constrained by it's relationship to the control point (usually either `f(point n) = y_n` or `f'(point n) = 0` or both (but you get to decide).

How many matching constraints you can have depends on the number of degrees of freedom (total number of constraints must equal total number of DoF, right?). You have have to introduce some extra endpoint constraints in the form `f''(start) = 0` ... to get it right.

At that point you're just looking at a lot of tedious algebra to earn how to translate this into a big system of linear equation which you can solve with a matrix inversion.

Most numeric methods books will cover this stuff.

Comment: alright, thanks for the answer... I guess you got me hooked and I'll ty to use cubic splines.

Comment: I found something nice here: http://www.korf.co.uk/spline.pdf They describe how to create splines that don't overshoot and may be calculated without having to solve a matrix etc.. basically its a simplification of a cubic spline, but it seems to do exactly what I need. Wrote some C++ code according to their math. Looks pretty good so far. However, I am not sure how I would introduce a parameter that allows to manipulate the steepness of the curve. Will need to work on that. Hints anyone?

Comment: @codey: The spline described in that paper allows you to obtain the solution a closed form before you begin. That's not always possible. After I wrote this answer it occurred to me to wonder if you had looked into B-splines as an option. It's been a while since I used them so I'm not sure they will meet your needs, but they are characterized by straight-forward math.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to say about the spline described in the paper. Regarding Bezier- or B-splines: In their basic form they just approximate the points, so they don't go through the points. Then there are interpolating b-splines. They would probably work, but they also seem to be more costly to calculate. Secondly, they still might overshoot - so they don't meet my requirement about the y-Range.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason you cannot use splines. If you have a formulation/library for that that deals with increments, just step from the starting point to the end point of your graph with the desired number of points.

If you want more control over the behavior of the derivative at the control points, you can compose your own piece-wise polynomial that satisfy the conditions of continuity in the function and its derivative. These conditions end up as equations for a linear system of equations that you will then solve with matrix methods as you indicate. This is one way to clamp the derivative at zero for the endpoints.

The degree of freedom that allows you to broaden or narrow the peaks in the interpolated function are more ambiguous. One possibility is to order an otherwise under-determined set of equations by its properties in higher order derivatives, or by its deviation from the first order (linear) interpolator.

Good luck!

Comment: isn't the increment of a spline in relation to the x-Axis dependent on the location of the two points? If two points are close together regarding their x-values this would lead to more sample points on the x-axis than when they are close. So I would need to relate the number of sampling points to their x-Values(when not drawing the graph first). I guess, that should work. However, I was looking for a possibility to get the discrete values of such a function without that much computations involved. Same for the Matrices: It should work in theory, but isn't there something more elegant?

Comment: @codey: You're going to get a *piecewise function* as the output (that is what a spline is), which you can evaluate at arbitrary points. That is, you can draw the curve as densely and evenly as you want.

Answer (score -2):

Why not use well-known solutions to your problem?
Read about [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) and [polynomial regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression).
These are the algorithms you're looking for. 
UPDATE: polynomial one would be of your interests

Comment: On first sight they would... however, they are pretty unstable, which leads to not ending up with a "smooth" curve... For instance, place two points on the x-axis and the third somewhere else.. you end up with huge waves...

Comment: OP wants the curve to pass through all the control points, with the additional constraint that the slope is zero at the start and end points.  A linear or polynomial regression generally won't have those properties.

Comment: @codey: The polynomial results are smooth by the mathematical definition. What they are not is reliably possessed of zero slope at the ends.

Comment: @dmckee you are talking about smooth as being differentiable and continuos? (hope I picked the right words) I am not a mathematician, so I might be wrong on some expressions. However, what I need is a curve that is not only as smooth as possible, but also as "flat" as possible. I hoped the drawings would clearly illustrate what I am talking about.

Comment: what do you mean by 'unstable'? have you tried to implement it?

Comment: Well, either way the graph doesn't go through all points - it only approximates the graph, which is what regression usually is used for. Or you increase the degree. But than the behavior is similar to a polynomial interpolation, which is nothing I would describe as "flat". There is a applet to try it: http://www.arachnoid.com/polysolve/

Comment: @codey: I was talking about exactly that. I emphasized the "mathematical" part because I wondered if you meant something different. In order to deal with a desire for "flat"ness, we (or at least I) would need a more precise understanding of what you mean by that. The standard approach to spline will handle everything else for you, but does not really address that idea (don't fret the `s` parameter, it is there for convenience and can be translated into x very easily though this must be done on a segment-by-segment basis...).